# Custom legend for lattice levelplot or ggplot2 map R

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, gis, levelplot

Given the `code`, `map` and [sample data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zlO3UqIZOGHB-cEwO7mO_wnwVWx3d_5e) below:
instead of plotting names of `watersheds` etc on the map,how can I produce a seperate legend using `ggplot2`or `levelplot` just like one will do using `ArcGIS?` Basically, I will like to produce the legend shown on this map [image]preferably with `levelplot`or `ggplot2`.

`Code` and `map` are included as well as sample data for plotting in `R`.

```
require(colorRamps)
require(raster)
require(rasterVis)
require(mapproj)
library(raster)    
library(proj4)


# Get province borders and project it to same CRS than raster
can1 <- getData('GADM', country="CAN", level=1)
getData('ISO3') # country name
dem=getData('alt', country='CAN', mask=TRUE)


require( colorRamps )
my.at <- unique(round(seq(ceiling(5800), floor(1), length.out = 51),0))#at: numeric vector specifying where the colors change. must be of length 1 more than the col vector.

myColorkey <- list(at=my.at,space = "bottom", tck = c(0,0),## where the colors change 
                   labels=list(axis.line = list(col = NA),at=myat1,rot=0,cex=1.4,font=1,
                               fontface=1),height=0.99,width=1.8)

col<-colorRampPalette(c("#d9d9d9", "#bdbdbd", "#969696", "#737373", "#525252", "#252525", "#000000"))


levelplot(dem,maxpixel=ncell(dem),panel=panel.levelplot.raster,names.attr=names(dem),
          interpolate=F,margin=FALSE,xlab=list(label="Longitude",cex=1.5),yscale.components = yscale.raster.subticks,
          xscale.components = xscale.raster.subticks,
          ylab=list(label="Latitude",cex=1.5),
          par.strip.text=list(cex=1),xlim=c(-158, -48.99485),
          ylim=c(38.00513, 85),col.regions=col,at = seq(0, 5800,100),
          colorkey = list(space = "bottom", labels = list(at = seq(0, 5800,800), rot=0,cex=1.1,font=6,fontface=1,
                                                          labels =c("0",  "800", "1600", "2400", "3200", "4000", "4800", "5600")),
                          height=0.99,width=1.8,tck = c(0,0)),
          par.settings=list(panel.background=list(col="white"),axis.line=list(lwd=1.9), strip.border=list(lwd=1.9),layout.heights=list(xlab.key.padding=-0.2)),
          cex=0.8, scales = list(x=list(draw=TRUE,cex=1.2), y=list(draw=TRUE,cex=1.2)))+
 layer(sp.polygons(can1,lwd=0.5,col="gray40"))+
 layer(sp.polygons(watershed,lwd=1,col=c("#a6cee3", "#1f78b4", "#b2df8a", "#33a02c", "#fb9a99", "#e31a1c", "#fdbf6f", "#ff7f00"),
                   fill=c("#a6cee3", "#1f78b4", "#b2df8a", "#33a02c", "#fb9a99", "#e31a1c", "#fdbf6f", "#ff7f00")))+
 layer(sp.polygons(lake,lwd=1,col="cadetblue1",fill="cadetblue1"))+
 layer(sp.lines(river,lwd=0.5,col="blue4"))+
 layer(sp.text(coordinates(watershed), txt = watershed$NAMRB_EN, pos =c(1,1,3,3,1,4,1,1),col="black",font=list(face="bold"),cex=0.8))
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: `myat1` is unassigned.

Comment: What is the purpose of the map? I would try to get rid of the color-filled polygons when I am interested in the elevation and just plot the boundaries of each watershed. For example, the Columbia watershed in the ArcGIS map completely destroys the information on elevation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adapt your code to [this example](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Multiple-legends-with-levelplot-and-spplot-td7587300.html) to have a legend both for watersheds and elevation:

```
library(sp) 
library(raster) 
library(rasterVis) 

f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster") 
r <- raster(f) 

data(meuse) 
coordinates(meuse) = c("x", "y") 
meuse$class <- cut(meuse$zinc, 3) 

ptsCols <- c('black', 'red', 'blue') 

lvp <- levelplot(r, margin = FALSE, 
                 ## Define the legend for the spplot graphic 
                 key = list(space = 'top', text = list(levels(meuse$class)), 
                     points = list(pch = 21, fill = ptsCols)), 
                 ## Legend for the Raster object 
                 colorkey=list(space="right",width=0.75,height=0.75)) 

spp <- spplot(meuse["class"], col.regions = ptsCols) 

lvp + spp
```

Comment: Thanks @Christpher. what about the lakes and rivers in the legend?

Comment: @christopher how can we replace the points in key to numerals??